# How to get logs from ASP.Net MVC application in docker logs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, docker

I created a basic ASP.Net MVC application and then created an image and spun a windows container, and when I do docker logs I do not see any logs from the application. Can someone guide me please.

Below is what I have done.

1. Created ASP.Net MVC application
2. Did a `FilePublish` to bin folder
3. Created below Docker File

   ```
   FROM microsoft/aspnet

   COPY ./bin/Release/Publish/ /inetpub/wwwroot
   ```
4. Built the image like - `docker build -t myImg .`
5. Ran the container on Windows Docker like - `docker run -p 8081:80 --name mycontainer5 myImg`
6. Opened the website in browser
7. Now when I check `docker logs {conatainerId}` **I don't see anything there**
8. Code Snippet-

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       [DllImport("kernel32")]
       static extern bool AllocConsole();
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           AllocConsole();
           Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
           Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out));
           Trace.AutoFlush = true;
           Trace.WriteLine("HelloWorld");
           StreamWriter standardOutput = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
           standardOutput.AutoFlush = true;
           Console.SetOut(standardOutput);
           Console.Out.WriteLine("My Logs");
           Console.WriteLine("test");
           return Content("kklj");
       }
   }
   ```

**Expectation** - I just want to see some logs from any of my Action Methods.

[image]

Comment: Does ServiceMonitor swallows all the logs??